# how to pass Data for DataTable using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to download HTML table contain data in Excel and pdf with pagination and many other functionality for that I am using `jquery Datatable` for that I am using **DataTable** But while passing data in `Datatbale` its showing **Invalid JSON response**.
So How can i pass data in JSON Format. I am using `JSON.stringfy(Parameter)`.

can any one help me how to pass data for 'Datatable'

```
var params = {
                UserName: $('#txtUserName').val(), UserID: $('#txtUserIDEdit').val(),
                Status: $('input[name="Status"]:checked').val()
            };
```

**Onsuccess of AJAX**

```
$('#test').DataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "pageLength": 10,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "searching": true,
                    "order": [],
                    'serverMethod': 'post',
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "MobileUser_Login.aspx/Get_Data",
                        "dataType": "json",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "data": function (params) {
                            return JSON.stringify(params);
                        }
                    },
                    buttons: ['csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'pageLength']
                });
```

**WEB method returning sample data**

[image]

**On console windows**

[image]

**That function not returning any value**

Can any one help why Datatable function not returning any value i have passed correct URL, correct Type i.e. `POST` where i am doing mistake please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your backend is returning but it can be only one of two:

A correct application/JSON return then you do not need to change the returned object at all, or it’s returning the JSON as plain/text, then you have to JSON.parse() and not JSON.stringify()

Comment: Thanks for quick response i tried with `JSON.parse()` but on console window i am getting `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: Take a look at the developer tools of your Browser what is retuned by the backend call.

Comment: it seems returning `json` only sample data `PASSWORD: "123"
Status: "Active"
USER_LOGIN: "1212"
USER_NAME: "nitish"` kindly check my updated code

Comment: In that case you do not need to convert it an any case. Just return the response

Comment: i just simply did like this `"data": function (d) { return d; }`  but again same error i am getting i dont understand why ?

Comment: this data is not comma separated. due to this error is coming ?

Comment: Please take a look at the Webbrowsers developer tools what is returned by the server.

Comment: That `function (d){return d;}` not returning any value. Why it so Please guide me